# MySQL Workbench allow remote connections

Tags: mysql, remote-access, mysql-workbench

How can I allow remote connections to databases with MySQL Workbench?

Trying to connect to a database on an external  host and it refuses the connection.

Port 3306 is forwarded correctly.

Comment: Did you configure a user for remote access in the MySQL database and give that user the proper permissions to access the DB you want it to access? Can you provide the specific error text or an error code?

Answer (score 2):

From the server:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '{USER}'@'{IP{' IDENTIFIED BY '{PASSWORD}' with grant option;
```

- {IP} is the IP you want to allow access. You can use % to accept any IP address
- {USERNAME} is the user you use to connect
- {PASSWORD} the password you use to connect
- To confirm the change do ...

  ```
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  ```